# Uncaught Reference Error: stLight is not defined (in Chrome only)

Tags: javascript, django, google-chrome, cross-domain

My web page ends thus:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">var switchTo5x=false;</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
stLight.options({publisher: "ur-24e62f76-1f66-e3aa-1190-c533b729ca11", doNotHash: true, doNotCopy: true, hashAddressBar: false});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>  
</body>
</html>
```

In FireFox and Safari, it behaves. In Chrome:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: stLight is not defined nectar-tugg-art:229
(anonymous function)
```

In other words, the code at w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js has failed to execute, and hence, failed to define the stLight variable.

The page is part of a Django web application running on a remote server. Saving the generated HTML page locally, then viewing in Chrome, works correctly.

At this point I'm stuck. Something to do with the cross domain security model? There aren't any security exceptions.

Some weird interaction with the other javascript files?

The static (generated) code is [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/767553/stlight-test.html). It won't run from Dropbox though.

Comment: check your console, is there any errors prior to this

Comment: No, none. Further information: making a local copy of buttons.js, and referencing that, works fine - no error.

Comment: it seems to be working fine http://plnkr.co/edit/tewbsUoOUSPaiEEofsmn?p=preview

Comment: Yeah - as I said, a local static copy of the HTML page works fine for me as well. I'm really curious why it fails under this one circumstance: remote deployment, Chrome, remote script.

Comment: is there a possibility of your script that calls `stLight` being evaluated before the script from sharethis.com has finished loading?

Comment: Got the problem, your remote html is running on SSL but the script is from non secured site

Comment: It's actually not HTTPS.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Ok, think I may have found it: the site runs fine in Chrome's *incognito* (porn) mode. So I strongly suspect I've got some kind of extension that's interfering with it (like Do Not Track or something).

EDIT
It's Collusion's "block known tracking sites" feature.

Comment: "porn mode" made my day

Answer (score 8):

In my case I found it to be a Chrome plugin called "Disconnect". Thanks to @SteveBennet for the clue.

Answer (score 5):

In my case I replaced

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>
```

this by

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ws.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>
```

[ShareThis](http://support.sharethis.com/customer/portal/articles/475097-ssl-support#sthash.bIavEhsp.dpbs)

Answer (score 2):

In Magento stLight is not defined:
This can be resolved by following:
`<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){ stLight.options({publisher: "ur-24e62f76-1f66-e3aa-1190-c533b729ca11", doNotHash: true, doNotCopy: true, hashAddressBar: false});}
</script>`

Issue (I think) is js file `http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js` load after the script in which this function exists. so easiest solution in my mind is window.onload, may have other good solutions.

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by the [Ghostery](https://www.ghostery.com/) extension, in addition to the extensions listed in the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you switched on the SSL on your site, you might want to try re-writing your ShareThis script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ws.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  stLight.options({
    publisher:'12345',
  });
</script>
```