# ShareThis buttons not clickable on HTTPS website

Tags: javascript, html, security, https, sharethis

I have added "share this" buttons to my secure site and now they produce an error when clicked. Errors are mentioned below.  Has anyone had this problem before?

> Blocked loading mixed active content "http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"
>
> ReferenceError: stLight is not defined
>
> Loading mixed (insecure) display content on a secure page "http://w.sharethis.com/images/facebook_32.png"

Answer (score 12):

Basically if a page is loaded over HTTPS then every resource it uses should also be loaded over HTTPS. It's a part of browser security policy, just like [Same-Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) etc.

Fortunately ShareThis can be used over HTTPS like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ws.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    stLight.options({
        publisher:'12345',
    });
</script>
```

Same applies to your facebook icon. Just use this URL: https://ws.sharethis.com/images/facebook_32.png

Comment: @user2434592 did you tried the solution I suggest? Do you need some additional clarification?

Comment: their certificate is invalid

Comment: @MichaelJohnston - Note that the _domain_ also has to be changed (https://ws.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js) - ws instead of s.sharethis.com. See [this support article|https://support.sharethis.com/hc/en-us/articles/217916188-Moving-from-HTTP-to-HTTPS-SSL-Support]. Probably some dumb legacy CDN reason why they can't just use the same domain with https:// :P

Answer (score 1):

Also for those that are having trouble debugging this stuff make sure to check out that your browsers aren't blocking ShareThis through an add-on.

Ref: [stLight not defined issue related to addons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16139354/uncaught-reference-error-stlight-is-not-defined-in-chrome-only)